# Why does the image file size change so much when saving from PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a PNG which is 1.27mb. 
If I open it in Paint and save it out as a JPG, it becomes 943kb.
If I then take that JPG into Photoshop and save it over the same JPG, with the quality set to 12, it save out at 1.73mb, higher than the original PNG!
If I take the original PNG into PS and save it out as a JPG, it's 1.82mb.

What's happening here?

Comment: Photoshop could have increased(a software technique) the dpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that PS is using different compression techniques for both PNG and JPG. It is up to the program to decide how to implement the PNG and JPG compression techniques.

Comment: They surely are, but how can saving it from Photoshop make the image larger than the original? Is it adding a bunch of metadata to the image or something?

Comment: Yes it could be Meta, it could also be doing more or less passes of the compression techniques than paint. As cybernard said, the DPI could be mucked around by PS. All things in our control, but unlikely to create predictably sized lossy photos when compared to other programs.

Comment: Le up-vote ;0 ?

Comment: I am reputation poor...